# Revisit : $20\choose 5$ subsets without 3,4 or 5 consecutive numbers

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, inclusion-exclusion, combinatorics-on-words

Addendum-2 just added to my question.

---

Addendum just added to my question.

---

$\underline{\textbf{Overview}}$

This is a **self-answer** question of
[this original question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4360142/20-choose-5-without-3-4-and-5-consecutive-numbers).
I strongly suspect that the original question will soon be closed and then deleted.

> I’m trying to get the amount of combinations of 5 numbers from one to twenty
> without duplicates and without 3,4,and 5 consecutive running numbers.

$\underline{\textbf{Clarification}}$

Let $N = \{1,2,\cdots, 20\}$.  
How many distinct subsets of $N$ are there where:

- The subset has exactly $5$ elements.
- The subset does **not** contain $3$ consecutive elements. 
  Here, consecutive elements are elements $(k), (k+1), (k+2).$

For example, both of the following sets are satisfactory:

- $\{1, 2, 4, 5, 7\}$
- $\{1, 3, 5, 7, 9\}$.

Further, each of the following sets are unsatisfactory:

- $\{1, 2, 3, 14, 18\}$
- $\{2, 3, 4, 5, 17\}$
- $\{8, 9, 10, 11, 12\}$.

$\underline{\textbf{My Background}}$

About $50$ years ago I took a Probability course in college and did ok.  I have
forgotten much of the theory, and usually rely exclusively on intuition to attack
Probability (or Combinatorics) problems.

If relevant, some decades ago I survived but have forgotten much of:

- "Real Analysis : Volume 1 : 2nd Ed." (Apostol, 1966).
- The first $(2/3)$ of "Elementary Number Theory" (Uspensky and Heaslett, 1938)
  [through quadratic reciprocity].

$\underline{\textbf{Problem Relevance}}$

In my experience, there are three typical approaches to this type of problem:

- The Direct Approach
- Recursion
- Inclusion-Exclusion

This particular problem interested me, because of the challenge involved in providing three distinct solutions, one for each of the above approaches.  However, exploring [Inclusion-Exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle),
I concluded that the math involved was too ugly to be reasonably feasible.

However, I was able to find two distinct Direct Approaches to offer.

$\underline{\textbf{My Work}}$

See my self - answers.  
For clarity, I have provided a separate answer for :

- A Direct Approach
- An Alternate Direct Approach
- Recursion

---

**Addendum**

Given the answers provided by others, it seems to me that the one pending challenge is to find some elegant solution that is based primarily on Inclusion-Exclusion.

I would be very interested if someone could present such a solution.

**Edit**
Mike Earnest added an Inclusion-Exclusion response to his answer.

---

**Addendum-2**

Finally conquered my own private Inclusion-Exclusion challenge for this problem.  Just added a separate Inclusion-Exclusion answer.

Comment: This question preparetion must be taught in schools to show how to ask a question in M.S.E..

Comment: By the way , in first glance , i found that the answer is $11,648$

Comment: @Bulbasaur I tried it three different ways, and got the same answer all $3$ times.  Have you found a flaw in any of my answers here?  Alternatively, if you post your answer, flag me, and I will look at it.

Comment: I posted it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of subsets, think of binary strings with $5$ ones and $15$ zeroes. Such a string can be uniquely represented as
$$
0^{z_1}\;1\;0^{z_2}\;1\;0^{z_3}\;1\;0^{z_4}\;1\;0^{z_5}\;1\;0^{z_6}
$$
For example, $(z_1,z_2,\dots,z_6)=(1,5,3,0,6,0)$ would represent $01000001000110000001$. Therefore, binary strings are in bijection with nonnegative integer solutions to the equation
$$
z_1+z_2+z_3+z_4+z_5+z_6=15.
$$
Such a solution will result in a binary string with three consecutive ones if and only if there exists an $i\in \{2,\dots,4\}$ for which $z_i=z_{i+1}=0$. By looking at the *largest* index $i$ for which $z_i=z_{i+1}=0$, we see that binary strings with three consecutive ones fall into three disjoint classes:

- $z_2=z_3=0$, $z_4>0$. (*The first three ones are consecutive, but not the first four*). Given this, $z_4-1$ is an arbitrary nonnegative integer, so we can count these by counting solutions to $z_1+(z_4-1)+z_5+z_6=(15-1)$, the number of which is $\binom{(15-1)+4-1}{4-1}=\binom{17}3$ via normal stars and bars.
- $z_3=z_4=0,z_5>0$. (*The middle three ones are consecutive, possibly including the first one, but excluding the last one*). By the logic, there are $\binom{17}3$ such solutions.
- $z_4=z_5=0$. (*The last three ones are consecutive, possibly including the second and first ones*). This time, there are $\binom{18}3$ solutions.

Therefore, the number of solutions without three consecutive ones is
$$
\binom{20}5-\binom{17}3-\binom{17}3-\binom{18}3=13{\,}328.
$$

It is also easy to rephrase this in terms of the principle of inclusion exclusion. Let...

- $A_1$ be the set of strings where the first three ones are consecutive.
- $A_2$ be the set of strings where the middle three ones are consecutive.
- $A_3$ be the set of strings where the last three ones are consecutive.

Using the $z_1+\dots+z_6=15$ paradigm, and applying PIE to count the intersection of the complemetnts of $A_1,A_2$ and $A_3$ (here, $AB$ denotes $A\cap B)$, we see
$$
\begin{align}
|A_1^c\cap A_2^c\cap A_3^c|
  &=\binom{20}5-|A_1|-|A_2|-|A_3|+|A_1A_2|+|A_1A_3|+|A_2A_3|-|A_1A_2A_3|
\\&=\binom{20}5-\binom{18}{3}-\binom{18}{3}-\binom{18}{3}+\binom{17}2+\binom{16}1+\binom{17}2-\binom{16}1
\end{align}
$$
Explanations:

- In $A_1$, we have $z_2=z_3=0$, which corresponds to solving $z_1+z_4+z_5+z_6=15$, the number of solutions to which is $\binom{18}3$. Same goes for $A_2$ and $A_3$.
- In $A_1A_2$, we have $z_2=z_3=z_4=0$, so $z_1+z_5+z_6=15$, counted by $\binom{17}2$. Same for $A_2A_3$.
- In $A_1A_3$, we have $z_2=z_3=z_4=z_5=0$, so $z_1+z_6=15$, counted by $\binom{16}1$. Same goes for $A_1A_2A_3$.

Comment: Very elegant.  See also the Addendum that I have just added to my question.

Comment: See edit for a PIE solution.

Comment: Nice thanks....

Comment: See also the Addendum-2 that I have just added to my question.

Answer (score 4):

According to the beautiful explanation , these $5$ numbers can consists of two ways suchthat

- No consecutive numbers
- Only one pair of consecutive numbers

So ,

- For no consecutive numbers :

Lets represent the numbers by letters such that the selected numbers is represened by $\color{blue}{S}$ , and non-selecteds by $\color{red}{S}$.

Now , we must have $15\color{red}{S'}$ and $5\color{blue}{S'}$. Now ,we will distribute these $5$ blue $S'$ among and ends of $15\color{red}{S'}$ . We can do it by $C(16,5)$ ways.For example , one of the distribution is $$\color{blue}{S}\color{red}{S}\color{red}{S}\color{red}{S}\color{blue}{S}\color{red}{S}\color{red}{S}\color{blue}{S}\color{red}{S}\color{blue}{S}\color{red}{S}\color{blue}{S}\color{red}{S}\color{red}{S}\color{red}{S}\color{red}{S}\color{red}{S}\color{red}{S}\color{red}{S}\color{red}{S}$$

Now , think that $$1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20=\color{blue}{S}\color{red}{S}\color{red}{S}\color{red}{S}\color{blue}{S}\color{red}{S}\color{red}{S}\color{blue}{S}\color{red}{S}\color{blue}{S}\color{red}{S}\color{blue}{S}\color{red}{S}\color{red}{S}\color{red}{S}\color{red}{S}\color{red}{S}\color{red}{S}\color{red}{S}\color{red}{S}$$

So , we select the numbers $\{1,5,8,10,12\}$

- For only one pair of consecutive numbers :

Select one of the possible place among $16$ gaps (ends and between the red letters), and place two blue letters in that place. We can do it by $C(16,1)$ ways.By using the same logic , select $3$ place for the remaining letters among $15$ suitable places by $C(15,3)$.For example , $$\color{blue}{S}\color{red}{S}\color{red}{S}\color{red}{S}\color{blue}{S}\color{red}{S}\color{red}{S}\color{blue}{S}\color{red}{S}\color{red}{S}\color{blue}{S}\color{blue}{S}\color{red}{S}\color{red}{S}\color{red}{S}\color{red}{S}\color{red}{S}\color{red}{S}\color{red}{S}\color{red}{S}$$

Above ,we select $\{1,5,8,11,12\}$

So , the answer is $$C(16,5) + C(16,1) \times C(15,3) = 4368+16 \times455 =11648$$

$\mathbf{EDITION}$: We can also have two separate consecutive numbers such as $\{1,2,5,7,8\}$

So , select $2$ places among $16$ suitable places by $C(16,2)$ to place double blue letters and select one place for the remaining by $C(14,1)$.

For example , $$\color{blue}{S}\color{blue}{S}\color{red}{S}\color{red}{S}\color{red}{S}\color{red}{S}\color{red}{S}\color{red}{S}\color{red}{S}\color{blue}{S}\color{red}{S}\color{red}{S}\color{red}{S}\color{red}{S}\color{red}{S}\color{red}{S}\color{red}{S}\color{red}{S}\color{blue}{S}\color{blue}{S}$$

We select $\{1,2,10,19,20\}$

So , the answer is $$C(16,5) + [C(16,1) \times C(15,3) ]+ [C(16,2) \times C(14,1)] = 4368+[16 \times455] +[120 \times 14] = \color{blue}{13,328}$$

Comment: You can have two separate pairs of consecutive numbers.  So, the combination $\{1,2,4,5,7\}$ is okay.  I think that that is where you went wrong.

Comment: Yeah i missed it , let me edit my answer

Comment: @user2661923 it has been edited .. i hope this answer save you these cumbersome processses

Comment: +1 : to your answer.  I did not study it that closely, but from what I saw, it looks good.  See also the answer of Mike Earnest, which I accepted.  Your answer and his were very similar.

Comment: See also the Addendum that I have just added to my question.

Comment: See also the Addendum-2 that I have just added to my question.

Answer (score 1):

$\underline{\textbf{Inclusion-Exclusion}}$

This answer is based on [Inclusion-Exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).  The answer contains certain shortcuts that simply didn't occur to me before.  That is why I originally (incorrectly) thought that Inclusion-Exclusion was not feasible for this problem.

---

For any set $T$ with a finite number of elements, let $|T|$ denote the number of
elements in $T$.

Let $N$ denote the set $\{1, 2, \cdots, 20\}.$ 
Let $A$ denote the following collection of subsets of $N$: 
$\{S \subseteq N ~: ~S ~\text{has exactly} ~5 ~\text{elements}\}.$

For $~k \in \{1, 2, \cdots, 18\}$:

Let $B_k$ denote the collection of all subsets $S$ in $A$ where:

- $S~$ specifically contains the elements $~(k), (k+1),~$ and $~(k + 2)$.

This means (for example) that if the subset $S$ is contained in $B_3$, that $S$ contains each of the elements $~(3), (4),~$ and $~(5).~$  This **also** means that $S$ might or might not not contain any of the elements $~(1), (2), (6),~$ or $~(7)$.

It is necessary to compute $\displaystyle ~|A| - |B_1 \cup B_2 \cup \cdots \cup B_{18}|.$

---

Let $~T_0~$ denote $~|A|~$.

Let $T_1$ denote $~\displaystyle\sum_{1 \leq i_1 \leq 18} B_{i_1}$. 
That is, $T_1$ represents the sum of $\displaystyle \binom{18}{1}$ terms.

Let $T_2$ denote $~\displaystyle\sum_{1 \leq i_1 < i_2 \leq 18} |B_{i_1} \cap B_{i_2}|$. 
That is, $T_2$ represents the sum of $\displaystyle \binom{18}{2}$ terms.

For $~r \in \{3,4,\cdots, 18\}$:

Let $T_r$ denote $~\displaystyle\sum_{1 \leq i_1 < i_2 < \cdots < i_r \leq 18} |B_{i_1} \cap B_{i_2} \cap \cdots \cap B_r|$. 
That is, $T_r$ represents the sum of $\displaystyle \binom{18}{r}$ terms.

Then, in accordance with Inclusion-Exclusion theory:

$$ |A| - |B_1 \cup B_2 \cup \cdots \cup B_{18}|
~=~
\sum_{r = 0}^{18} (-1)^r T_r. \tag1 $$

---

$\underline{\text{Intermediate Results}}$

The first time that I considered Inclusion-Exclusion for this problem, I overlooked the results of this section.

For $~r \in \{2, 3, \cdots, 18\},~$ consider 
$\displaystyle B_{i_1} \cap B_{i_2} \cdots \cap B_{i_r}
 ~: ~1 \leq i_1 < i_2 < \cdots < i_r \leq 18.$

**Intermediate Result-1 (IR-1)**: 
If $~i_r \geq (i_1 + 3)$ then
$~\displaystyle B_{i_1} \cap B_{i_2} \cdots \cap B_{i_r}~$
is the empty set.

Proof: 
Construct a subset $S$ from
$~\displaystyle B_{i_1} \cap B_{i_2} \cdots \cap B_{i_r}.$ 
Then $S$ contains the elements $~(i_1), (i_1 + 1), ~$ and $~(i_1 + 2).$ 
Further, $S$ also contains the elements $~(i_r), (i_r + 1), ~$ and $~(i_r + 2).$ 
Since $~i_r \geq (i_1 + 3)~$ this implies that the constructed subset $S$ contains $6$ distinct elements.

This is impossible, because each subset $S$ is part of the collection of subsets contained in $A$. This implies that the subset $S$ contains exactly $5$ elements.

Therefore, no such subset $S$ can be constructed. 
Therefore, the set $~\displaystyle B_{i_1} \cap B_{i_2} \cdots \cap B_{i_r}~$ equals the empty set.

**Intermediate Result-2 (IR-2)**: 
If $~i_r = (i_1 + 2)$ then
$~\displaystyle |B_{i_1} \cap B_{i_2} \cdots \cap B_{i_r}|~ = 1.$

Proof: 
Construct a subset $S$ from
$~\displaystyle B_{i_1} \cap B_{i_2} \cdots \cap B_{i_r}.$ 
Then $S$ contains the elements $~(i_1), (i_1 + 1), ~$ and $~(i_1 + 2).$ 
Further, $S$ also contains the elements $~(i_r), (i_r + 1), ~$ and $~(i_r + 2).$ 
Since $i_r = i_1 +2$, this implies that 
$S$ also contains the elements $~(i_1 + 2), (i_1 + 3), ~$ and $~(i_1 + 4).$

Since the subset $S$ contains exactly $5$ elements, 
the only possible subset $S$ is the set $\{i_1, i_1 + 1, i_1 + 2, i_1 + 3, i_1 + 4\}.$

Therefore, when $i_r = i_1 + 2$, 
$~\displaystyle B_{i_1} \cap B_{i_2} \cdots \cap B_{i_r}~$ only contains one subset.

The results **IR-1** and **IR-2** will significantly simplify the subsequent computations.

---

$\underline{\text{Computation of} ~T_0}$

As $A$ is defined:

$$T_0 = |A| = \binom{20}{5} = 15504. \tag2 $$

---

$\underline{\text{Computation of} ~T_1}$

To compute $T_1$, first consider a subset $S$ constructed from $|B_1|$. 
$S$ contains the elements $~(1), (2), ~$ and $~(3).~$ 
$S$ can also contain any $2$ of the elements from $\{4, 5, \cdots, 20\}.$

Therefore, $~\displaystyle |B_1| = \binom{17}{2}.$ 
The identical analysis will apply to each of
$~B_2, B_3, \cdots, B_{18}$.

Therefore,

$$T_1 = 18 \times \binom{17}{2} = 2448. \tag3 $$

---

$\underline{\text{Computation of} ~T_2}$

To compute $T_2$, first consider each of the following, separately:

- $B_{i_1} \cap B_{(i_1 + 1)}.~~$ Regard this as a type-1 set.
- $B_{i_1} \cap B_{(i_1 + 2)}.~~$ Regard this as a type-2 set.
- $B_{i_1} \cap B_{i_2} ~: i_2 \geq (i_1 + 3).~~$ Regard this as a type-3 set.

Construct a subset $S$ from $B_{i_1} \cap B_{(i_1 + 1)}$. 
Then, $~S~$ contains each of the elements
$~(i_1), (i_2), (i_3), ~$ and $~(i_4)$. 
$S~$ also contains one more element, which can be any of the other $16$ elements from $~\{1, 2, \cdots, 20\}.$

Therefore $~|B_{i_1} \cap B_{i_1 + 1}| = 16.$ 
Since $i_1$ can be any element in $~\{1, 2, \cdots, 17\},~$ there are $17$ possible type-1 sets.

Therefore, when computing $T_2$, the partial sum from type-1 sets is 
$\displaystyle (17 \times 16) = 272.$

Consider the type-2 set $~B_{i_1} \cap B_{(i_1 + 2)}.$ 
By **IR-2**, $~|B_{i_1} \cap B_{(i_1 + 2)}|~=~ 1$. 
Since $i_1$ can be any element in $~\{1, 2, \cdots, 16\},~$ there are $16$ possible type-2 sets.

Therefore, when computing $T_2$, the partial sum from type-2 sets is 
$\displaystyle (16 \times 1) = 16.$

In a similar fashion, **IR-1** implies that any type-3 set must be the empty set.

Therefore,

$$T_2 = 272 + 16 = 288. \tag4 $$

---

$\underline{\text{Computation of} ~T_3}$

To compute $T_3$, first consider each of the following, separately:

- $B_{i_1} \cap B_{i_2} \cap B_{i_3} ~: ~i_3 = (i_1 + 2).$ 
  Regard this as a type-2 set.
- $B_{i_1} \cap B_{i_2} \cap B_{i_3} ~: ~i_3 \geq (i_1 + 3)$. 
  Regard this as a type-3 set.

Consider the type-2 set
$B_{i_1} \cap B_{i_2} \cap B_{i_3} ~: ~i_3 = (i_1 + 2)$. 
By **IR-2**, $~|B_{i_1} \cap B_{i_2} \cap B_{i_3}|~=~ 1$. 
Since $i_1$ can be any element in $~\{1, 2, \cdots, 16\},~$ there are $16$ possible type-2 sets.

Therefore, when computing $T_3$, the partial sum from type-2 sets is 
$\displaystyle (16 \times 1) = 16.$

In a similar fashion, **IR-1** implies that any type-3 set must be the empty set.

Therefore,

$$T_3 = 16. \tag5 $$

---

$\underline{\text{Computation of} ~T_r ~: ~r \geq 4}$

Consider any of the $~\displaystyle \binom{18}{r}~$ sets 
$B_{i_1} \cap B_{i_2} \cap \cdots \cap B_{i_r}.$

Since $r \geq 4, i_r \geq (i_1 + 3).$ 
By **IR-1**, this implies that 
$|B_{i_1} \cap B_{i_2} \cap \cdots \cap B_{i_r}| = 0.$

This applies to each of the $~\displaystyle \binom{18}{r}~$ terms in the computation of $T_r.$

Therefore,

$$T_r = 0 ~: r \geq 4.\tag6 $$

---

$\underline{\text{Final Computation}}$

Using the results from (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), and (6) above:

$$\sum_{r = 0}^{18} (-1)^r T_r = \sum_{r = 0}^{3} (-1)^r T_r$$

$$= 15504 - 2448 + 288 - 16 = 13328.$$

Comment: very nice approach +1

Answer (score 0):

$\underline{\textbf{A Direct Approach}}$

For any set $T$ with a finite number of elements, let $|T|$ denote the number of
elements in $T$.

Let $N$ denote the set $\{1, 2, \cdots, 20\}.$ 
Let $A$ denote the following collection of subsets of $N$: 
$\{S \subseteq N ~: ~S ~\text{has exactly} ~5 ~\text{elements}\}.$

For $~k \in \{1, 2, \cdots, 18\},~$ 
let $B_k$ denote the collection of all subsets $S$ in $A$ where:

- $S~$ specifically contains the elements $~(k), (k+1),~$ and $~(k + 2)$.
- When $k > 1$, the subset $S$ does not contain the element $(k-1)$.

This means that if $S$ is in $B_k$, $S$ contains a group of (**at least**)
$3$ consecutive elements
such that the lowest element in this group is the element
$k$.  This implies that $B_1, B_2, B_3, \cdots, B_{18}$ are all disjoint sets.

This implies that the desired computation is

$$ |A| - \left[\sum_{k=1}^{18} |B_k|\right]. $$

---

To enumerate $|B_2|,~$ for any subset $S$ in $B_2$:

- $S$ does not contain the element $(1)$.
- $S$ does contain the elements $~(2), (3),~$ and $~(4)$.
- $S$ contains any $2$ *other* elements from $\{5, 6, \cdots, 20\}$.

Therefore

$$|B_2| = \binom{16}{2}.\tag1 $$

Similarly, for $k \in \{3, 4, \cdots, 16\}$, 
for any subset $S$ in $B_k$:

- $S$ does not contain the element $(k-1)$.
- $S$ does contain the elements $~(k), (k+1),~$ and $~(k+2)$.
- $S$ contains any $2$ *other* elements from the $16$ remaining elements in $N$.

Therefore

$$|B_3| = |B_4| = \cdots = |B_{16}| = \binom{16}{2}.\tag2 $$

---

$\underline{\text{Special Handling}}$

For $~k \in \{1, 17, 18\}$ the computation of
$|B_k|$ will need special handling.

For any subset $S$ in $B_1$:

- $S$ does contain the elements $~(1), (2),~$ and $~(3)$.
- $S$ contains any $2$ *other* elements from $\{4, 5, \cdots, 20\}$.

Therefore,

$$|B_1| = \binom{17}{2}. \tag3 $$

For any subset $S$ in $B_{17}$:

- $S$ does contain the elements $~(17), (18),~$ and $~(19)$.
- $S$ contains any $2$ *other* elements from either $\{20\}$ or
  $\{1, 2, \cdots, 15\}$.

Therefore,

$$|B_{17}| = |B_2| = \binom{16}{2}. \tag4 $$

For any subset $S$ in $B_{18}$:

- $S$ does contain the elements $~(18), (19),~$ and $~(20)$.
- $S$ contains any $2$ *other* elements from
  $\{1, 2, \cdots, 16\}$.

Therefore,

$$|B_{18}| = |B_2| = \binom{16}{2}. \tag5 $$

---

$\underline{\text{Final Computation}}$

Putting the computations in (1), (2), (3), (4), and (5) above all together,

$$|A| - \left[\sum_{k=1}^{18} |B_k|\right]$$

$$ = \binom{20}{5} - \left[17 \times \binom{16}{2}\right] - \binom{17}{2}$$

$$ = 15504 - \left[17 \times 120\right] - 136 = 13328.$$

Answer (score 0):

$\underline{\textbf{An Alternate Direct Approach}}$

For a set $T$ with a finite number of elements, 
let $|T|$ denote the number of elements in $S$.

Let $N$ denote the set $\{1, 2, \cdots, 20\}.$

Let $A$ denote the following collection of subsets of $N$: 
$\{S \subseteq N ~: ~S ~\text{has exactly} ~5 ~\text{elements}\}.$

Let $B$ denote the following collection of subsets $S$ that are elements in $A$:
$S$ has $3$ consecutive elements but does not have $4$ consecutive elements.

Let $C$ denote the following collection of subsets $S$ that are elements in $A$:
$S$ has $4$ consecutive elements but does not have $5$ consecutive elements.

Let $D$ denote the following collection of subsets $S$ that are elements in $A$:
$S$ has $5$ consecutive elements.

Let $a,b,c,d$ denote $|A|, |B|, |C|, |D|,$ respectively $\implies$

- $a = \displaystyle \binom{20}{5} = 15504.$
- The desired computation is $a - (b + c + d).$

---

$\underline{\text{To Compute} ~b}$

For $k \in \{1, 2, \cdots, 18\},$

- let $B_k$ denote the collection of subsets $S$ where 
  $\{S \in B ~: ~S ~\text{contains the elements} ~k, k+1, ~\text{and} ~k+2\}.$
- let $b_k$ denote $|B_k|$.

This implies that $\displaystyle ~b = \sum_{k=1}^{18} b_k$.

$\displaystyle b_1 = \binom{16}{2}$. 
This is because any set $S \in B_1$ contains the elements 
$(1), (2),$ and $(3)$ 
does not contain the element $(4)$, 
and contains $2$ elements from $\{5, 6, \cdots, 20\}$.

Similarly, $\displaystyle ~b_{18} = \binom{16}{2}.$

$\displaystyle b_2 = \binom{15}{2}$. 
This is because any set $S \in B_2$ contains the elements 
$(2), (3),$ and $(4)$ 
does not contain either of the elements $(1)$ or $(5)$, 
and contains $2$ elements from $\{6, 7, \cdots, 20\}$.

Similarly, for $\displaystyle ~k \in \{3, 4, \cdots, 17\}, ~b_k = \binom{15}{2}$.

Therefore,

$$b = \left[2 \times \binom{16}{2}\right] + \left[16 \times \binom{15}{2}\right] 
= 240 + 1680 = 1920.$$

---

$\underline{\text{To Compute} ~c}$

For $k \in \{1, 2, \cdots, 17\},$

- let $C_k$ denote the collection of subsets $S$ where 
  $\{S \in C ~: ~S ~\text{contains the elements} ~k, k+1, k+2, ~\text{and} ~k+3\}.$
- let $c_k$ denote $|C_k|$.

This implies that $\displaystyle ~c = \sum_{k=1}^{17} c_k$.

$\displaystyle c_1 = \binom{15}{1}$. 
This is because any set $S \in C_1$ contains the elements 
$(1), (2), (3)$ and $(4)$ 
does not contain the element $(5)$, 
and contains $1$ element from $\{6, 7, \cdots, 20\}$.

Similarly, $\displaystyle ~c_{17} = \binom{15}{1}.$

$\displaystyle c_2 = \binom{14}{1}$. 
This is because any set $S \in C_2$ contains the elements 
$(2), (3), (4)$ and $(5)$ 
does not contain either of the elements $(1)$ or $(6)$, 
and contains $1$ element from $\{7, 8, \cdots, 20\}$.

Similarly, for $\displaystyle ~k \in \{3, 4, \cdots, 16\}, ~b_k = \binom{14}{1}$.

Therefore,

$$c = \left[2 \times \binom{15}{1}\right] + \left[15 \times \binom{14}{1}\right] 
 = 30 + 210 = 240.$$

---

$\underline{\text{To Compute} ~d}$

For $S \in D$, there are $(16)$ possible choices for the lowest element in $S$.

$$d = 16.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Final Computation}}$

$$a - (b + c + d) = 15504 - (1920 + 240 + 16) = 13328.$$

Answer (score 0):

$\underline{\textbf{Recursion}}$

For any set $T$ with a finite number of elements, let $|T|$ denote the number of
elements in $T$.

For $~n \in \Bbb{Z^+},~$ let $~A_n$ denote the set $\{1, 2, \cdots, n\}.$

For $n \in \Bbb{Z^+}, ~n \geq 4, ~n \leq 20, ~k \in \{3, 4, 5\}$:

- let $~B_n^k ~$ denote the collection of subsets $~S \in A_n$ where 
  $S$ has exactly $k$ elements and 
  $S$ does not have (**at least**) $3$ consecutive elements.
- let $C_n^k ~$ denote the collection of subsets $~S \in B_n^k$ where 
  $S$ does not contain the element $(n)$.
- let $D_n^k ~$ denote the collection of subsets $~S \in B_n^k$ where 
  $S$ does contain the element $(n)$ but does not contain the element $(n-1)$.
- let $E_n^k ~$ denote the collection of subsets $~S \in B_n^k$ where 
  $S$ does contain both of the elements $(n)$ and $(n-1)$.

Let $~b(n,k), ~c(n,k), ~d(n,k), ~e(n,k),~$ denote 
$~|B_n^k|, ~|C_n^k|, ~|D_n^k|, ~|E_n^k|,~$ respectively.

This implies that $~b(n,k) = c(n,k) + d(n,k) + e(n,k).$

The final answer will be $b(20,5)$.

---

The spirit of this approach would
have me compute $b(n,4)$ recursively, and then compute $b(n,5)$ recursively.  This
would lengthen the answer.  Instead, I am going to implememt a moderate compromise.

I will compute $b(n,4)$ directly, in a manner similar to that taken in the Direct
Approach answer.  Then, I will compute $b(n,5)$ recursively.

---

$\underline{\text{Direct Computation of} ~b(n,4)} ~: ~5 \leq n \leq 20$

There are $~\displaystyle \binom{n}{4} ~$ subsets of $A_{n}$ that contain
exactly $4$ elements.

For any such pertinent subset $S$ that has exactly $4$ consecutive elements, there are
$(n-3)$ possible choices for the lowest element in $S$.

For any such pertinent subset $S$ that has exactly $3$ consecutive elements
(i.e. but not $4$ consecutive elements), there are $(n-2)$ possible choices for the
lowest element of the $3$ consecutive elements in $S$.

If the lowest of the $3$ consecutive elements in $S$ is either $1$ or $(n-2)$, then
the set $S$ can be constructed in $(n-4)$ ways.  If instead, the lowest element in $S$ is
between $2$ and $(n-3)$ inclusive, the set $S$ can be constructed in $(n-5)$ ways.

Therefore

$$b(n,4) = \binom{n}{4} - (n - 3) - \left[2 \times (n - 4)\right] - \left[(n-4) \times (n-5)\right]$$

$$ = \binom{n}{4} - (n - 3) - \left[(n-3) \times (n-4)\right] $$

$$ = \binom{n}{4} - (n - 3)^2.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Recursive Computation of} ~b(n,5)} ~: ~7 \leq n \leq 20$

To compute $~e(n,5) = |E_n^5|,$ first consider the computation of $b(n-3, 3)$ and
then consider the compuation of $c(n-2,3)$.

To compute $b(n-3,3)$ consider that there are $\binom{n-3}{3}$ ways of selecting
$3$ elements from $A_{n-3}.$  If such a subset of $A_{n-3}$ does have $3$ consecutive
elements, then there are $(n-5)$ choices for the lowest element in the subset.

Therefore, $\displaystyle ~b(n-3,3) = \binom{n-3}{3} - (n-5) = \binom{n-3}{3} - n + 5.$

Further, there is a bijection between $B_{n-3}^3$ and $C_{n-2}^3.$  That is, simply
start with any subset that is in $B_{n-3}^3$ and **do not use** element $(n-2)$.

Similarly, there is a bijection between $C_{n-2}^3$ and $E_n^5$.  That is, simply
start with any subset that is in $C_{n-2}^3$, and **do use** both of the elements
$(n)$ and $(n-1)$.

Therefore,

$$e(n,5) = c(n-2,3) = b(n-3,3) = \binom{n-3}{3} - n + 5.$$

---

Similarly, there is a bijection between $D_n^5$ and $C_{n-1}^4$.  Simply start with
any subset that is in $C_{n-1}^4$ and **do use** element $n$.

Also, there is a
bijection between $C_{n-1}^4$ and $B_{n-2}^4.$  Simply start with any subset that is
in $B_{n-2}^4$ and **do not use** element $(n-1)$.

Therefore,

$$d(n,5) = c(n-1,4) = b(n-2,4) = \binom{n-2}{4} - (n - 5)^2.$$

---

Finally, there is a bijection between $C_n^5$ and $B_{n-1}^5.$  Simply start
with any subset that is in $B_{n-1}^5$ and **do not use** element $n$.

It should be noted that $B_6^5$ is the empty set, so $c(7,5) = b(6,5) = 0.$

So, $$c(n,5) = b(n-1,5).$$

Also, for $n \geq 7$, you have that

$$b(n,5) = c(n,5) + d(n,5) + e(n,5).$$

---

$\underline{\text{Tabular Computation of} ~b(n,5)} ~: ~7 \leq n \leq 20$

The following table may now be generated.

\begin{array}{| r | r | r | r | r |}
\hline                       
n & c(n,5) & d(n,5) & e(n,5) & b(n,5) \\
& = b(n-1,5) & = \displaystyle \binom{n-2}{4} 
& = \displaystyle \binom{n-3}{3} 
& = c(n,5) \\   
& & - (n - 5)^2 
& - n + 5 
& + d(n,5) \\ 
& & & & + e(n,5) \\
\hline                       
6 & & & & 0 \\
\hline
7 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
\hline
8 & 3 & 6 & 7 & 16 \\
\hline  
9 & 16 & 19 & 16 & 51 \\
\hline
10 & 51 & 45 & 30 & 126 \\
\hline  
11 & 126 & 90 & 50 & 266 \\
\hline
12 & 266 & 161 & 77 & 504 \\
\hline  
13 & 504 & 266 & 112 & 882 \\
\hline
14 & 882 & 414 & 156 & 1452 \\
\hline  
15 & 1452 & 615 & 210 & 2277 \\
\hline
16 & 2277 & 880 & 275 & 3432 \\
\hline  
17 & 3432 & 1221 & 352 & 5005 \\
\hline
18 & 5005 & 1651 & 442 & 7098 \\
\hline  
19 & 7098 & 2184 & 546 & 9828 \\
\hline
20 & 9828 & 2835 & 665 & \color{red}{13328} \\
\hline   
\end{array}